# Is Percona backwards compatible with MySQL? The Ruby on Rails Case

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, percona

I'm starting a Ruby on Rails project and I'm interested in using Percona as my DBMS.
I've read that Percona is fully compatible with MySQL tooling

**I wonder if I can use Ruby on Rails tooling with Percona (using the MySQL support)?**

Comment: I believe that you can although, I have never tried it personally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you have the mysql client libraries you should be able to build the mysql gem which is the interface rails (through active record) uses to interact with mysql.

You may have to pass the percona mysql_config when building the gem like so:

```
gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/percona-xtradb/bin/mysql_config
```

If you are using the mysql2 gem you "shouldn't" need to do this (I think)

Comment: Did this work? If so, I'm curious as to how you installed percona as it's not working for me. All my attempts end in failures indicating that the dev libraries are not present, strengthened by find / -name mysql.h returning nothing on my host. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I recently switched to Percona as well, you just need to install the mysql development library they provide, for ubuntu/debian you need to run: sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev

Install mysql/mysql2 gems as normal, no need to specify mysql_config location.

Answer (score 1):

I'm on CentOS 5 using Percona 5.5 and was having trouble installing the mysql gem. And as mentioned above, you just need the appropriate percona devel libraries for your system.

Get them here: http://www.percona.com/downloads/Percona-Server-5.5/

If you have Ruby 1.8.5, install the gem with:

```
gem install mysql --no-ri --no-rdoc -v 2.7  -- --build-flags --with-mysql-config
```

If you have 1.8.6 or above, use:

```
gem install mysql --no-ri --no-rdoc -- --build-flags --with-mysql-config
```

You might be able to omit some of those parameters, but that is what I've found to work well given the different Ruby versions..