# Installing ruby mysql gem with percona server

Tags: mysql, rubygems, centos, percona

New install of cent os 5.4; clean install of percona xtradb server (Server version: 5.1.56-rel12.7 Percona Server (GPL), 12.7, Revision 224) gem install mysql failed with the output

```
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... yes
checking for mysql_ssl_set()... yes
checking for rb_str_set_len()... yes
checking for rb_thread_start_timer()... no
checking for mysql.h... no
checking for mysql/mysql.h... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
```

which appears to indicate it can't find the dev libraries. I know I'd normally use the additional options -- --with-mysql-lib=... but I don't believe they're installed as part of the normal percona install outlined here: [percona repositories info](http://www.percona.com/docs/wiki/repositories:start)

So I tried doing yum install mysql-devel but get a conflict with the percona stuff. I [found this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6279755/is-percona-backwards-compatible-with-mysql-the-ruby-in-rails-case) where the proposed solution was using the --with-mysql-config option. Percona doesn't automatically install a my.cnf at /etc/my.cnf upon installation, so I whipped one up and placed it there because that's where the init.d script for mysql checks for it. Restarted mysql, confirmed that it's now loading that configuration and attempted the install again, but still failed with

`"Exec format error - /etc/my.cnf --cflags (Errno::ENOEXEC)"`

Thanks for any help

I also did a find / -name mysql.h and nothing, so it looks like the required libraries are not present after installing both percona server and client with yum

Comment: after a day of dicking with this, I bailed and went back to plain vanilla mysql. Literally a minute later and I'm good to go. Bummer, I know percona rocks, but had to get something running on the server, so perhaps I can upgrade at some point in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you correctly added **Percona yum repository** you just need to install the `Percona-Server-devel` package:

```
yum install Percona-Server-devel-55
```

Replace 55 with the Percona Server version you're currently using.

After that, mysql gems will install correctly.

Comment: thank you, Azad. I'll give this a try soon, and if it works, will accept the answer. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I've reinstalled libmysqlclient-dev from Percona.

And then reinstalled mysql & mysql2 gems.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more; I don't understand your answer. I'd love a solution and would be more than happy to accept your answer if it works. Thanks

Comment: sorry, missed word. Reinstalled

Comment: Thanks Alex. Just to be clear, you reinstalled this separately/in addition to the server package, correct? Sorry for potentially being dense; thought it better to just ask now... Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

After troubling hours and hours and many hours:

Found the following to install mysql gem with percona 5.6:

http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.6/release-notes/Percona-Server-5.6.16-64.1.html

> gem uninstall mysql
>
> apt-get remove mysql-server mysql-server-5.5 mysql-client
>   mysql-client-5.5 mysql-client-core-5.5 mysql-server-core-5.5
>   mysql-common libmysqlclient18:i386 libmysqlclient18:amd64
>
> apt-get install percona-server-server-5.6 percona-server-client-5.6
>
> cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
>
> mv libmysqlclient.so.18.0.0 libmysqlclient.so.18.0.0-backup
>
> ln -s libperconaserverclient.so.18.1.0 libmysqlclient.so.18.0.0
>
> rm -rf /home/slat/.rvm/gems/ruby-XXXXX/gems/mysql*
>
> gem install mysql

YIHAA - It works!

Answer (score 0):

For any new people trying to install this gem (this question shows up highly in search ranks), make sure you're passing the mysql directory, like:

```
 gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-dir=/usr/local/mysql
```